# Lightning Wallet bulk creation

Tags: lightning-network, paper-wallet, gifting-bitcoin

I want to giveaway small amounts of BTC on lightning. The ideal method is a wallet paper equivalent, this means no coupons, websites or redemption procedures. I still have some doubts about the process.

1. Can I do this without running my own node?
2. Any special safety precautions?<
3. Can you give me high level overview of the how the generation may look?

Thanks in advance for your time.